# Entity Framework only performs cascading delete when debugging

Tags: entity-framework, cascading-deletes

I've got the following classes:

```
public class Discount 
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Region> Regions { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public int DiscountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Discount Discount { get; set; }
    public int Region { get; set; }
}
```

And when I delete a discount, I want it to do a cascading delete on the associated regions, using this code:

```
foreach (var discount in discounts) {
    context.Discounts.Remove(discount);
}
```

When calling `context.SaveChanges()` the following error occurs:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Region_dbo.Discount_DiscountId". The conflict occurred in database "Portal", table "dbo.Region", column 'DiscountId'.

But if I debug the above `for` loop, and just after it removes the discount from the context I inspect the removed discount, it shows it has 0 regions. Then when calling `context.SaveChanges()` it works!

Any idea what's going on, and how I can get it to work when not debugging?

Answer (score 0):

OK - I've just realised you can't have cascading deletes when lazily loading objects, which makes sense.